# SQL how to write query to make average depending on status of communication

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

I've table with count of deposits made by users with communication. But i just can't get based on this average number of deposits made by users in each project, depending on state - did the user have received email or not.

Code:

```
select a.project_id, player_external_id, COUNT (player_external_id)
FROM gamestorage.exchanged_orders a
INNER JOIN gameanalytics.users_analytics b
ON a.player_external_id = b.external_id
WHERE TYPE ='deposit'
  and status='success'
  and payment_type='normal'
  and amount>=0
    and receive_emails = true
  Group BY 1,2
```

Of course, i can make two queries like `receive_`*`emails = true, receive`*`_email = false`, and then find average, suffering from big amount of rows and making double work. But i'm very sure there is more convenient way. How i should filter and transform results depending on state of communication (column 'receive_emails')?

Answer (score 0):

Other Way:

```
select a.project_id, COUNT (player_external_id)
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN receive_emails = true THEN player_external_id ELSE NULL END) / COUNT (player_external_id) as "Subscribed"
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN receive_emails = false THEN player_external_id ELSE NULL END) / COUNT (player_external_id) as "Unsubsribed"
FROM gamestorage.exchanged_orders a
INNER JOIN gameanalytics.users_analytics b
ON a.player_external_id = b.external_id
WHERE TYPE ='deposit'
  and status='success'
  and payment_type='normal'
  and amount>=0
  Group BY a.project_id
```

Comment: yes, that's good way to solve the problem but there is big result. maybe my question has written not correct. what i'm trying to get it's like this: column 1 Project id column 2, average deposits per user on project with receiving emails 3. average deposits per user oon project without emails

Comment: i can just remove player_external id. is it correct?

select a.project_id, COUNT (player_external_id)
, COUNT(CASE WHEN receive_emails = true THEN player_external_id ELSE NULL END) / COUNT (player_external_id) as "Subscribed"
, COUNT(CASE WHEN receive_emails = false THEN player_external_id ELSE NULL END) / COUNT (player_external_id) as "Unsubsribed"

Comment: and one more - how i can filter results, to show me more than 0?